# How can i call pl/sql stored procedure (function, returning number value)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL developer, or Oracle SQL* Plus

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In SQL Plus you can do this:

```
var x number
exec :x := myfunction();
```

Or you may be able to use SQL:

```
select myfunction() from dual;
```

Comment: I can't select because I have an update statement inside the sql function. The exec... works. Thanks!

Comment: Whats the fullpath? What if it's a function or procedure you are testing that's in a package?

Answer (score 3):

The example above shows how to call a function from SQL*Plus. If you're calling a function from a PL/SQL procedure, see the example below.

```
DECLARE
    x NUMBER;
BEGIN
    x := myfunction();
END;
```

---

A more complex example that will return a value of 100 (10*10):

```
DECLARE

  x NUMBER;

  FUNCTION mysquare(in_y IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN in_y * in_y;
  END mysquare;

BEGIN

  dbms_output.enable;
  x := mysquare(10);
  dbms_output.put_line(x);

END;
```